# Getting data from an interface list

Tags: c#

Here's the snippet:

```
interface ITween
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public class TweenElement<T> :ITween
{
    public Action<T> Setter;
    public T from;
    public T to;
    public float time;
    public float currentTime;
    public EasingType easing;
    public TweenType type;
    public bool deleteAtEnd = false;
    public Func<bool> Trigger;
    public Action Callback;
    void ITween.DoStuff() { }
}

private List<ITween> tweens = new List<ITween>();
```

How do I get data from the list beside deriving from a non generic base class instead of interface? list[o].from doesn't work.

Comment: What if two classes implement `ITween` interface with only one of them containing this  `.from` property?  An apple and orange are fruit but it doesn't mean that *any* random fruit is an apple. You could add this field to existing interface or create a new one. However it looks like XY problem

Comment: Without background information it's hard to help you in the right direction. If _all options_ are open you could change the interface to `ITween<T>` and add a `T from` property. But is `ITween` supposed to expose that property?

Comment: Your list doesn't promise to contain anything except some type of object with a DoStuff() method. This *might* be one of your TweenElement<T> objects, or could be something totally unrelated.

Comment: Do you have control over `TweenElement` class or does it come from external library ?

Comment: `if (list[o] is ITween<SomeType>) { SomeType fromValue = ((ITween<SomeType>) list[o]).from; }` But then again, as others already said, it smells a bit like a XY problem or poor design choice...

Comment: @ Fabjan yes, I do control that class. I derived from an interface just to be able to use a single list for varoius type of elements.